# No se dispara el evento MouseDown en una Imagen

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

estoy trabajando con xaml y tengo un problema, el evento MouseDown no se esta ejecutando cuando doy doble clic sobre una imagen, así es como tengo el código:

```
<Grid x:Name="gridContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Image x:Name="bgImageDge" Source="/Resources/LineaDge.png" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="20" Stretch="Uniform" Mouse.MouseDown="bgImageDge_MouseDown"></Image>
    <Image x:Name="bgImageMachineControl" Source="/Resources/LineaCM.png" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="20" Stretch="Uniform" Mouse.MouseDown="bImageMachineControl_MouseDown"></Image>
    <Image x:Name="bgImageSectionControl" Source="/Resources/LineaCS.png" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="20" Stretch="Uniform" Mouse.MouseDown="bgImageSectionControl_MouseDown"></Image>
    <Image x:Name="bgImageContainerHanding" Source="/Resources/LineaME.png" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="20" Stretch="Uniform" Mouse.MouseDown="bgImageContainerHanding_MouseDown"></Image>

</Grid>
```

Lo que quiero es que al dar doble clic sobre la imagen abra otro userControl.
Tengo varias imágenes y si activo los eventos en codebehind se ejecutan todos al dar clic en una imagen.

Comment: Prueba con el evento MouseDown del control.

Comment: Primero, no sabemos que control estás usando, ya que `OpaqueClickableImage` no es un control standard wpf. Por otro, veo que el evento que estas usando es el `MouseMove`, no el `MouseDown`

Comment: ¿Ya probaste con el evento `MouseLeftButtonDown`?